# ftp and http are very slow with IIS on windows server 2016

Tags: iis, ftp, http, windows-server-2016, file-transfer

I had Cenots with proftpd ftp server and I was getting the maximum upload speed my connection can reach.

However we had to convert this server to windows server 2016. I installed IIS from server manager and configured the ftp settings.

The server has 1 gbps connection. the download I get when downloading from this windows server is 30% of what my internet can reach with any other website/my own linux servers hosted in the same DC.

I even tried installing windows on some other servers that worked fine with linux, and I have the same issue, the upload and download speed from client side to the server running IIS is very slow.

Speeds with my 30 mbps internet:

- upload from my pc to IIS server with ftp: 400 KB/s
- upload from my pc to my other linux servers with ftp: 400 KB/s
- HTTP download from IIS server : 500 KB/s
- HTTP download from any website/my other linux servers : 2500 KB/s

Speeds from another colleague on 80 mbps internet:

- upload from his pc to IIS server with ftp: 1200 KB/s
- upload from his pc to my other linux servers with ftp: 1200 KB/s HTTP download from
- IIS server : 2500-4000 KB/s HTTP download from any website/my other
- linux servers : 8500 KB/s

I will be so grateful if someone can tell me why IIS ftp and http are so slow compared to apache/proftpd on linux and how do I fix these issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, first question, did you turned off on the NIC QoS? Windows tend to reserve a lot of bandwidth for himself (+-80%)

Comment: @yagmoth555.Thanks for your reply. I disabled QOS from my ethernet settings under "change adapter settings". Is there anything else I should do?